# CreateprocesswithLogonw returning success in spite Application doesn't started

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to invoke an admin manifested application, from the application which is running in standard user execution level with createprocesswithLogonw function. Function returns success but target application doesn't starts. The target application requires command line arguments which I'm passing by filling them in command parameter. The target application starts with shellexecute perfectly.
So i want to know:
1) why target application not starting even when we get success in CreateprocesswithLogonw? 
2) is there any possibility of build version impact on the invocation?

Comment: 1. Normally such error will not occur. I have never met this issue. The function return success without program not running and the program can be run by shellexecute. We shouldbetter make sure that CreateprocesswithLogonw has been run,you should set breakpoint to ensure this.  2.https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw     you can check this link. Its Minimum supported client is xp, So  build version didn't affect the function

Comment: @SuarezZhou-MSFT,Thanks for your input. I resolved the issue and the cause is very silly.The Target application requires Command line arguments to execute and they are not provided correctly. CreateProcessWithLogonw invoking target application but it is returning without notifying invoker or User. If target application has some logic to notify the return then it would have captured early.